# Server shutdown when stress

Tags: linux, windows, security, supermicro, xeon

Today I have a little problem. I have a local server in my house, for testing and virtualization. It has a Supermicro X8DT3-LN4F board and two Intel Xeon x5680 processors.

The problem is that when it suffers a lot of CPU consumption, for example in Linux performing tests from the terminal with `stress` or in Windows I tried a mining program, the board begins to beep and beep until the entire system shuts down.

I have not been in a similar situation before, normally when the processor has many processes it just stops them. I am a bit lost, any help or solution is welcome.

Comment: Check your fans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like overheating.  Modern motherboards will shut off if the CPU reaches a certain temperature.  Try installing a monitoring program that will tell you what the CPU temperature is in real time.  CPU temps shouldn't be going over 80C.  Modern CPUs also throttle when they get too hot so that is another way to tell.  On Windows look at the performance tab in task manager.  If your CPU is throttled under 1Ghz at 100% load you're overheating bad.

Comment: Yes. It seems to be that. On the official page of the processor it says that it does not have thermal control. It is the downside of buying an old processor. What I am going to do is underclock to the limit that it does not turn off and I will try to change the fans and buy a better paste. Thanks!